# How to get 10 random strings for a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

Hi guys i want to know how to create a method that take randomly 10 strings from a set of strings (around 96 string) in an array in java...

the strings are taken form a text file
and i already created a method to read the file and assign variable to the lines
and i have created an array of Questions also

this is my code for reading the file and creating a Question array

q is question

a choice a

b ....

.

.

cA is the correct answer

```
public static Question[] readAllQuestions() throws FileNotFoundException {
    int numberOfQuestions = CountQuestions();
    Question [] allQuestions = new Question[numberOfQuestions];
    Scanner file = new Scanner (new File("TestBank.txt"));
    String q = "";
    String aa = "";
    String bb = "";
    String cc = "";
    String dd = "";
    String ccA = "";
    int x = 0 ; 
    int k = 0 ; 
    while (x< (allQuestions.length-1)) {
        while (file.hasNext() && k == 0) {
            String ques[] = file.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int ww = 0 ; ww< ques.length ; ww++) {
                q += ques[ww];
                q+=" ";
            }
            if(ques[0].equals("")) {
                k++ ; 
            }
        }
        while (k == 1) {
            String a[] = file.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int ww = 0; ww< a.length; ww++) {
                aa += a[ww];
                aa+= " ";
            }
            if(a[0].equals("")) {
                k++ ;
            }
        }
        //file.hasNext() &&
        while (k == 2) {
            String b[] = file.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int ww = 0 ; ww< b.length ; ww++) {
                bb += b[ww];
                bb+= " ";
            }
            if(b[0].equals("")) {
                k++;
            }
        }
        while (k == 3) {
            String c[] = file.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int ww = 0; ww<c.length; ww++) {
                cc += c[ww];
                cc+= " ";
            }
            if(c[0].equals("")) {
                k++;
            }
        }
        while (k == 4) {
            String d[] = file.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int ww = 0; ww< d.length; ww++) {
                dd += d[ww];
                dd+= " ";
            }
            if(d[0].equals("")) {
                k++;
            }
        }
        while (k == 5) {
            String cA[] = file.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int ww = 0; ww<cA.length; ww++) {
                ccA += cA[ww];
                ccA += " ";
            }
            if(cA[0].equals("")) {
                k++;
            }
        }
        while (k == 6) {
            Question question = new Question(q,aa,bb,cc,dd,ccA);
            allQuestions[x] = question;
            q="";
            aa="";
            bb="";
            cc="";
            dd="";
            ccA="";
            x++;
            k=0;
        }
    } 
    return allQuestions;
}
```

any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Random** class. `array[random.nextInt(array.length)]`gives element of array indexed at any number from `0` to `array.length - 1` as the last index is excluded in `nextInt` method.

```
public static String[] getRandomStrings(String [] mainStrings, int i) {
    String [] randomStrings = new String[i];
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int index = 0; index < i ; index++){
        randomStrings[index] = mainStrings[random.nextInt(mainStrings.length)];
    }
    return randomStrings;
}
```

Comment: it worked, but when i print the array it prints the address only not the data!

Comment: Use loop to print elements.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you want 10 random strings from an array of strings without selecting duplicates. One simple way to accomplish this is by using [Collections::shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) to randomly permute the elements and then selecting a subset of the shuffled list. Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String[] exStringArray = IntStream.range(0, 96)
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .toArray(size -> new String[size]);

    System.out.println(getRandomElements(Arrays.asList(exStringArray), 10));
}

private static <T> Collection<T> getRandomElements(Collection<T> c, int maxElements)
{
    List<T> deepCopiedList = new ArrayList<>(c);
    Collections.shuffle(deepCopiedList);
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(deepCopiedList.subList(0, Math.max(Math.min(deepCopiedList.size(), maxElements), 0)));
}
```

Comment: Override toString